# What is the difference between Wordpress and Webmatrix

Tags: wordpress, webmatrix

Which one is the best option to start off a web project in?
I know Wordpress can be used from within WebMatrix as well, but can it independently function on its own and get the sites done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WordPress is a standalone Content Management System. WebMatrix is a web development tool which can be used to author PHP files (which is what WordPress uses). You would only do that if you wanted to customise your WordPress system, but most users do not need to do that.

You do not need WebMatrix to work with WordPress sites, but for a beginner, it provides a fairly hassle free way to get your WordPress site up and running. WebMatrix includes a web server and will configure your WordPress site to get up and running on that.

Answer (score 2):

**WebMatrix** is a free tool that allows you to create, customise and publish websites. To get started you can select an application from the built-in gallery such as **DotNetNuke**, **Umbraco**, **WordPress** and **Joomla** or you can create your own master piece from scratch.
  Webmatrix makes it easy to install and develop for **Drupal** on Windows, bringing open source applications to a whole new audience. As Drupal is as much a **framework** as it is a **CMS**, including it in the package makes it possible for any kind of web application to be developed on Webmatrix.

Note: **Microsoft** has been active in the Drupal community for a few years, and the community is proud that Drupal has been recognised as one of the best CMS and development frameworks available and selected by Microsoft for inclusion in Webmatrix.

Comment: Where did you copy and paste that from? Some attribution would be good.